# Golf Me a World Clock 

Tags: code-golf

#### Task

Write a program or function that takes as input a time in UTC, and outputs the equivalent time in **5 different cities** around the world. The cities displayed are up to the programmer, but the **time must be different** in each city.

To prevent golfers from using overly obscure city names, the city names used must appear on this list: [World Cities](https://pastebin.com/xmRiwZiQ)*, which corresponds to the list of cities and times found [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/).

As usual, [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1062#1062) are forbidden, including fetching data from an external source.

*The times provided in the pastebin use daylight time and assume that the time is 0:30 UTC.

#### Example

Given as input 12:30AM, your output might be:

```
Athens: 3:30AM
London: 1:30AM
New York: 8:30PM
Seoul: 9:30AM
Beijing: 8:30AM
```

#### Input

You may take input in any reasonable format. You can choose to take the time as 24-hour time, or 12-hour time with `AM` and `PM`. Specify the input format in your answer.

#### Output

Output may also be in either 12-hour or 24-hour time. The city-time pairs may be in any order and any reasonable format, so long as it is possible to associate each city with the corresponding time.

Daylight Savings Time can safely be ignored (ie. you can either use the offsets from the pastebin above, or you can assume that all times are in daylight time, or alternatively all in standard time)

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Happy golfing!

Comment: What is the format of the pastebin file? For instance, what does "London, 01:30" mean? (If DST are ignored, London should be UTC+0.)

Comment: @Arnauld Ah yes, the pastebin times use daylight time and are in reference to UTC 0:30. I'll specify that in the question

Comment: So, should we ignore the times in this file and just use it as a list of allowed cities?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, you can ignore the times in that file. They might be useful to calculate the offset from UTC for a given city though

Comment: `kyiv 
lima 
rome 
oslo 
suva 
doha` is what everyone will do, just making it simpler.

Comment: @dingledooper The times are required

Comment: Can I print all cities first, then times, in the same order?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Yes, that's fine

Comment: Do the cities need to be spelt exactly as in the Pastebin, or could e.g. `DC` be used for `Washington DC`, `Peking` for `Beijing` or `Rio` for `Rio de Janeiro`?

Comment: @Duncan They should be spelled exactly as in the pastebin (you can ignore accents on letters though)

Comment: Would it be ok if I output more than 5 cities? And would it be ok to prepend the continent to the city name (e.g. “America/New_York” instead of “New York”?

Comment: @agtoever Sure, I don't see why not

Comment: I smell a Mathematica built-in.

Comment: A regex generator might be handy for this challenge

Answer (score 26):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum).

24-hour time, input as `hours, minutes`.

```python
h,m=input();i=h
exec"print'ALCADcaamucgimbroraaasoni'[i-h::5],i%24,m;i+=1;"*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P0Mn1zYzr6C0REPTOtM2gyu1IjVZqaAoM69E3dHH2dElOTExtzQ5PTM3qSi/KDExsTg/L1M9OlM3w8rKNFYnU9XIRCfXOlPb1tBaScv0/38DHQVjAwA)

Example output for `0, 30` (12:30AM):

```python
Accra 0 30
Lagos 1 30
Cairo 2 30
Amman 3 30
Dubai 4 30
```

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VOwGCEyGD8LiQPR0RsYh2pUOlBIxcHT43vxSy5Qm7PTfkSKb5KquAILFEiCge5TDspERkqVXSY7HwD@PW70OwcGgCcQVisaM2xauhpV2fba59xo0TU/)

Comment: @SurculoseSputum thanks a lot. For some reason I thought I need an additional UTC+5 city.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P0Mn1zYzr6C0REPJMTm5KNEnMT2/2DkxsyjfMTc3Mc@lNCkxU0mTKy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1TTqqAoM69EI0M7U1PVyEQn9/9/Qx0FYwMA) by moving cities to `input('`...`')` prompt, albeit at the cost of readability. `AccraLagosRomeKyivDubai` can save another two.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for the suggestion, but I feel like this will be too similar to the other Python answer.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>71</s> 65 bytes

*Save 2 bytes using @dingle dooper's printing through `input()` trick!*

```python
t=input('Accra Lagos Rome Kyiv Dubai ')
exec"print t%24,;t+=1;"*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8Q2M6@gtERD3TE5uShRwScxPb9YISg/N1XBuzKzTMGlNCkxU0Fdkyu1IjVZqaAoM69EoUTVyETHukTb1tBaScv0/38jI21D0ywA)

Takes input as a complex number (e.g `01:30` is inputted as \$1+30i\$), and prints out the list of cities, then the corresponding times. Uses 24-hour time.

Comment: The spaces could be left out, saving 5 bytes, and the comma in `print t%24,` can also be left out for another 1 byte

Comment: @Duncan thanks! It seems like most answer does have separator between city names and times, so I'll keep the spaces for now.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```bash
for c in Amman Dubai Kabul Dhaka Seoul;{ TZ=Asia/$c date +$c\ %R -d$1Z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCFZITNPwTE3NzFPwaU0KTFTwTsxqTRHwSUjMTtRITg1vzTHulohJMrWsTgzUV8lWSElsSRVQVslOUZBNUhBN0XFMMq69v///4aWViamAA)

Input is passed as an argument, and output is on stdout. Both are in 24-hour time.

Answer (score 6):

## Google Sheets, <s>82</s> <s>77</s> 80 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes by finding a shorter list of city names that are all off by 1 hour.*
*Added 3 bytes thanks to Surculose Sputum pointing out that I was referencing the wrong list.*

```
=ArrayFormula(Split("Lagos,Rome,Kyiv,Dubai,Kabul",",")&Mod(A1+Column(A:E),24)&B1
```

Sheets will automatically add the trailing parentheses. Hours are input in `A1` and minutes in `B1`.

`Split(~)` gives us the list of city names.
`A1+Column(A:E)` iterates the input time by ones.
`Mod(~,24)` accounts for when the clock rolls to the next day.
`Split(~)&Mod(~)&B1` tacks on the minutes.
`ArrayFormula(~)` makes the whole thing work on arrays instead of just the first value.

[image]

There aren't any delimiters between the city name and the time because pretty costs bytes. It's fairly easy to distinguish between the end of the name and the start of the time, though, since none of the city names have numbers in them.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Could you be more specific? All 5 listed appear in [OP's list](https://pastebin.com/xmRiwZiQ) of allowed cities.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum My apologies. I had gotten the two lists confused in my copies. I have corrected the city names now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-93, 238 bytes

```
&&\" arccA",,,,,,:.\:.\" nammA",,,,,,3+:345*+`!v v    <
>    v v          `+*543:+3,,,,,,"Dhaka "\.:\.:_#<83*-^
^-*38>#_         :.\:.\" luoeS",,,,,,3+:345*+`!v v    <
>    v v          `+*543:+3 ,,,,,"Suva " \.:\.:_#<83*-^
^-*38>#_:.\:.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X00tRkkhsSg52VFJBwys9GKASEkhLzE3FyZmrG1lbGKqpZ2gWKZQpgAENlx2IArKg4AEbS1TE2MrbWOIHiWXjMTsRAWlGD0rIIpXtrEw1tKN44rT1TK2sFOOh2uD2ZdTmp8aTJZ9ChD7gkvLgNYp4LAPbI3D//@GllxG5gA)

Reads the hour and minutes from the input. For each city, except the first, it adds 3 to the hour, then checks whether it exceeds 23. If it does, it makes a small loop to subtract 24. The rest is just printing strings, moving the PC around and swapping the hours/minute to/from the top of the stack.

Comment: You can take the input in reverse order, removing the need for the initial *swap*: https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X01NSSGxKDnZUUkHDKz0YoBISSEvMTcXJmasbWVsYqqlnaBYplCmAAQ2XHYgCsoDgwRtLVMTYyttY4gWJZeMxOxEBaUYPSsgile2sTDW0o3jitPVMrawU46H6YLZllOanxpMjm0KENuCS8uAlingsA1si8P//0bmXIaWAA

Comment: And the *subtract 24*-part for `Amman` can be moved to the front: https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X01NSSGxKDnZUUkHDKz0YoBISSEvMTcXJmasbWVsYqqlnaBYxqVsY2GspVtmpwAEZUCokKCtZWpibKVtDFGr5JKRmJ2ooBSjZwVE8VwKcSCVNnG6WsYWdsrxCjDzc0rzU4MxzQeZCFTOhTAfCuDWKECsCS4tA9qiALUG4qo4Lpg1YFsc/v83MucytAQA. The same may be possible for `Suva`, but this is a little bit trickier

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for shaving off 7 bytes.

```
”Accra‡¸«ÄçªâÈ”#ε¹N+24%²»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX//@KAnUFjY3Jh4oChwrjCq8OEw6fCqsOiw4jigJ0jzrXCuU4rMjQlwrLCu///MjEKMDA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 32 bytes

Just another port of Surculose Sputum's answer. It produces quite an ugly output, due to joining by newlines.

```
”Accra Lagos«Ä KyivâÈ”#ε¹N+24%²»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNcx@TkokQFn8T0/OJDqw@3KHhXZpYdXnS4AyilfG7roZ1@2kYmqoc2Hdr9/7@RIZeBAQA)

## Explanation (for both)

```
”...”           Compressed string with the cities
     #          Space-split
      ε         Map:
                    Implicit current city pushed
       ¹            First input:
        N+              Add by the iteration counter
          24%       Modulo by 24
             ²      Append the second input
              »     Join the whole stack by newlines.
```

Comment: -2 byte using a compressed string instead of dictionary string: `.•Eān³ûζǝ₃δb¶«Ív¢L•™`

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX//@KAnUFjY3Jh4oChwrjCq8OEw6fCqsOiw4jigJ0jzrXCuU4rMjQlwrLCu///MjEKMDA) by using `London` and `Baghdad` instead of `Lagos` and `Kyiv`, which are part of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

## [q](http://kx.com/download), <strike>43</strike> 40 bytes

```
{`Accra`Cork`Rome`Doha`Dubai!x+60*til 5}
```

No Tio unfortunately for q

q has built in time types that you can perform arithmetic with, so simple enough

```
Example:
q){`Accra`Cork`Rome`Doha`Dubai!x+60*til 5}00:30
Accra| 00:30
Cork | 01:30
Rome | 02:30
Doha | 03:30
Dubai| 04:30
```

Comment: If you can change, try using Doha (https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/qatar/doha) instead of Ammon.

Comment: Thanks Ismael! Switched from Lagos to Cork and Cairo to Rome aswell

Comment: in k4 this is down to 37 bytes {`Accra`Cork`Rome`Doha`Dubai!x+60*!5}

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 26 bytes

```
5ɾ+₆+24%$S+`∴∷₇›†↵ƈ…±↑`5/Y
```

[Try It Online!](https://vyxapedia.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCI1yb4r4oKGKzI0JSRTK2DiiLTiiLfigofigLrigKDihrXGiOKApsKx4oaRYDUvWSIsIiIsIiIsIjBcbjMwIl0=)

Takes in `<hour>` `<minute>`, outputs an interleaved list of `<time>|<city>`.

My first Vyxal answer... it took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out how to properly deal with input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>118</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>76</s></sup> 75 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [Duncan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72002/duncan)!!!
Saved a whopping <s>18</s> <s>39</s> <s>41</s> 42 bytes thanks to [David G.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90945/david-g)!!!

```bash
for d in Accra Lagos Rome Kyiv Dubai;do date -d$1Z+$((i++))hour +$d%R;done&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCsIwFAXQvV9xhyoJoZAqLjoJbjp1dEuTFxPQPGkbQcRvj/kAz3xGM4fic7JL5AQvJD7F8wSHmHC0djK4mBvPGPhBOL/jC6c8mnhwDGcWQufa/qpaIaJSUgbOE1TrVkMNidbl23j0m/1WN/Od6IldQzYwuv9q1rrm8gM)

Input passed as command line argument.
Outputs to stdout.
Uses 24-hour time  format.

Comment: `("Accra""Lagos""Rome""Kyiv""Dubai")` saves four bytes at the cost of readability. Printing without a space saves another byte.

Comment: @Duncan Unfortunately, the first one just merges all the cities into one big string. But, although it's not as pretty, the second abides by the rules (I think) so nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: c=(Accra Lagos Rome Kyiv Dubai) saves ten bytes.  Shells only need quotes if something is special.  So you can save five more by remove all the " and ' on the second line, and putting a \ before the space in the -d option.  Save one more by removing the space between the -d and its parameter.  (101)

Comment: Changing %H:%M to %R can save 3 btyes.  Might be specific to the version of date, but works on TIO.

Comment: @DavidG. Yes, I do know that (use bash a lot) but totally missed it. Didn't know about`%R` though. Really nice golfs - thanks! :D

Comment: @Noodle9 - you missed dropping the space between -d and $1today...

Comment: Another big one:  Since none of the city names include a %, you can put the ${c[d]} between the + and the %R, and eliminate the printf altogether.  It think that brings it down to 90.

Comment: A weird one:  eliminate c, make d iterate over the names, set "i=" before the loop, use $d instead of ${c[d]} and $((i++)) instead of $d.  seems to save another 7 characters.  If you are willing to trust that i is undefined, you can save 3 more by not initializing it at all.

Comment: Two more, if you've done the previous.  The escaped space before "hour" is needed when writing "$d hour" but not if writing "$((i++))hour"  In the former case, writing "$dhour" became a 5 character variable reference.

Comment: I decided to see what I could do with GNU date...   Instead of "today", one can write "jan1" or "Mon", or even just the letter for ones local timezone (which for TIO, would be "Z").  Alas, if you put nothing there, the "+2hour" becomes the timezone.

Comment: @DavidG. Wow! Unfortunately, `i` has to be initialised because you must be able to rerun functions. Fantastic golfing - thanks! :D

Comment: While i does have to be initialized, it does not have to be 0. blank works. It turns out that the $(( )) construct treats empty variables as 0. If you want, you can make it a one liner by using a space or ; instead of newline between the i= and for. Doesn't save bytes, but can be cute.   Another twist.  If you enclose the line in parentheses, the use of the variable is in a subprocess, so doesn't survive.  So if we can assume i (or some variable) to be uninitialized, it won't be afterwards either.   And (xxx) is one byte shorter than i=;xxx

Comment: @DavidG. Ah yes, running it all in a sub-shell does the trick! Nice one - thanks again! :D

Comment: If I had known I was going to shorten it by 1/3...   :-)     xxx& instead of (xxx) works, unless you try two invocations ( f 12:30; f 16:16 ) and expect to be able to reasonably read the results.  I note it but do not recommend it.

Comment: @DavidG. Yes, you'd be well in your rights to have posted this as your own separate answer now. Hey ho. Using the idea of running it all as a background task as that's allowed (I believe - it's certainly better than relying on one-off initialisations) - thanks one more time! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 92 bytes

```c
i;f(h,m){for(i=0;i<5;)printf("%s %d:%d;","AccraLagosRome.Kyiv.Dubai"+6*i++,(h+i)%24,m);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jQydXszotv0gj09bAOtPG1FqzoCgzryRNQ0m1WEE1xUo1xVpJR8kxObkokcEnMT2/mCEoPzeVQc@7MrOMQc@lNCkxU0nbTCtTW1tHI0M7U1PVyARoonXt/9zEzDwNoNEaBjrGBiABAA)

Port of Bash, didn't check map

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 94 bytes

```c
i;f(h,m){for(i=0;i<15;i+=3)printf("%s %d:%d;","AccraAmmanDhakaSeoulSuva"+2*i,(h+i)%24,m);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDsIgEABAnmJISBbBBFu9iD008Qd9wWYrsqlQg9aL8e1Yr3MY2t2IamUfINqkP2EuwJ3zfN4fPZuu1Y/C@RVAqudGjSc1emllT1RQ9ClhFpeIE4rhOi93MSxvlKbZsoVoWKvmsJ7@WxNyhjUHZ1v3hx8)

Port of Python solution, didn't check map

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+Ɱ5%24;€⁹“F=ẓŒMdƲEṢ$Ṛ.»
```

A full program accepting two arguments, hours then minutes, which prints in an ugly format. Uses `Algiers Amsterdam Amman Dubai Islamabad` since they are the alphabetically earliest allowed cities with DST offsets of `1-5` hours from UTC.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//K@KxrjUlMjQ74oKs4oG54oCcRj3hupPFkk1kxrJF4bmiJOG5mi7Cu////zIy/zQ1)**

#### How?

```
+Ɱ5%24;€⁹“F=ẓŒMdƲEṢ$Ṛ.» - Main Link: hour, H; minute M
 Ɱ5                     - map across [1..5] with:
+                       -   addittion (to H)
   %24                  - modulo by 24
        ⁹               - chain's right argument, M
      ;€                - concatenate to each
         “F=ẓŒMdƲEṢ$Ṛ.» - compressed string "Algiers Amsterdam Amman Dubai Islamabad"
                        -   (this new niladic chain forces the previous result to be printed)
                        - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
Ｅ⪪”↶+∧e-|GT⊘"↘w⌊⎇*↔ＪAN·”⁵⪫⟦ι﹪⁺Ｉθκ²⁴η⟧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dck9C8IwEIDhv3JkukCEUnVyEjuVFguO4nBGMMGjV/Ph3z8zvM/y@kDJC7HqkuJacKYNbxvHgubsfaKJ3pKvmQUGCQRDfVI0Do7WwShxxXt0MMursuDCNeOFcsFvu59Wf2iEhwMDxlp7Uu1g3@nux38) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @SurculoseSputum's Python answer. Takes input as separate hours and minutes and uses the 24 hour clock. Explanation:

```
  ...               Compressed string of five cities
 ⪪   ⁵              Split into substrings of length 5
Ｅ                   Map over each substring
        ι           Current substring
           Ｉθ       Input hours as a number
          ⁺  κ      Plus current index
         ﹪    ²⁴    Modulo literal 24
                η   Input minutes
      ⪫⟦         ⟧  Joined with spaces
                    Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), 98 bytes

```
((h,m)=>['Accra','Lagos','Rome','Kyiv','Dubai'].map((e,i)=>console.log(e+' '+(h+i)%24+':'+m+';')))
```

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/8zofL7g9/)

Get the original idea from the C and so the Python guys.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `(e,i)=>console.log(e+' '+(h+i)%24+':'+m+';')` into ``(e,i)=>console.log`${e} ${(h+i)%24}:${m};` ``. You can save 1 more byte by changing `['Accra','Lagos','Rome','Kyiv','Dubai']` into `'Accra0Lagos0Rome0Kyiv0Dubai'.split(0)`. If you don't mind, you can save 1 byte by changing `(h,m)=>` into `m=>h=>`, requiring you to call it as `(m=>h=>[...])(30)(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.4+, 96 bytes

Yes, it's a fat boy :(
But was fun to write it!

```
foreach([Accra,Lagos,Cairo,Doha,Dubai]as$k=>$v)echo"\n$v ",date(H_i,strtotime("$argn {$k}hour"));
```

Run this with `php -r` (produces warnings).

The input format is flexible, as long as it can be interpreted by [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).
You can input hours in 12-hour or 24-hour formats, being displayed in 24-hour format.

The cities chosen were picked because they are NOT in DST at the time of this answer:
[image: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/?sort=2]

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 81 bytes

```javascript
(h,m)=>'Accra-Lagos-Rome-Kyiv-Dubai'.split`-`.map(e=>console.log(e,h++%24+':'+m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoMgFADQrxkqeiVqD2NgMNjbeuoLuhMrh@5KltDX2zk/LJjt5tMO5VFnU/mqojA9e1m7IQy4UIaRooPP6Qu8jy96pnMKfp9g0hETd6a39M8UnA60cKdWKW/tXbInk1GIOvO2U10j6gU)

Comment: Wow - first time I seen this syntax of avoiding parentheses on the `split` function. Can you provide some reference?

Comment: I think this way you can call any function with one parameter.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions The syntax used in the `.split` is allowed when you have a template string (the string with the accent character) as the only argument, which allows you to remove the parenthesis. However, using a number, in this case, removes the need for the template string. As I've suggested to another answer, using `'Accra0Lagos0Rome0Kyiv0Dubai'.split(0)` has the same exact size, but is easier to read and understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 65 bytes

Input `f(h)(m)`. Outputs an array of arrays: `[[City, mm, ss], ...]`.

```javascript
h=>m=>`Accra
Lagos
Rome
Kyiv
Dubai`.split`
`.map(c=>[c,h++%24,m])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/w9Yu19YuwTE5uSiRyycxPb@YKyg/N5XLuzKzjMulNCkxM0GvuCAnsySBK0EvN7FAI9nWLjpZJ0NbW9XIRCc3VvN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfroGF2eahpGxpoaxgSaX5n8A)

---

## JavaScript, 66 bytes

Prettier. Outputs a string with `City,mm,ss` separated by newlines.

```javascript
h=>m=>`Accra
Lagos
Rome
Kyiv
Dubai`.replace(/.+/g,M=>[M,h++%24,m])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBC8IgFADgc@9/BIrmYuvQRSHoVrt0jWAvcc7Q3tAS@vX2fS@sWGwO62dXj23WbdEmaTOdrM0IV/RU4EbJweUXKpy/TwyTym6NaB3rlOh8kqM291EuQmz7g0wP3iy9C0WnInkGm5n1A2fDngNvfw)

---

## JavaScript, 64 bytes

Uglier. Outputs a string without delimiters: `Citymm,ssCitymm,ss...`.

```javascript
h=>m=>`Accra Lagos Rome Kyiv Dubai `.replace(/ /g,_=>[h++%24,m])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/w9Yu19YuwTE5uShRwScxPb9YISg/N1XBuzKzTMGlNCkxUyFBryi1ICcxOVVDX0E/XSfe1i46Q1tb1chEJzdW839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ugYXZ5qGkbGmhrGBJpfmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Just realized that my language is such a bad language. It doesn't even support dumping the stack...

```
☻|▓■°u:"≡∟◘Σ≡☺╖ⁿ╩]┼ε╝╣╗à_∙▬Cô\K←û
```

Uncompressed:

```
"3@374Ry<+o;<r>YwI+eA78P`5a(c0[+24mc1[{M
```

### Explanation

```
"3@374Ry<+o;<r>YwI+eA78P`                % Compressed string containing the cities
                         5             M % In the range 1..5:
                          a              %    The current counter,
                           (             %    Decremented,
                            c0[+         %    Is added to the hours
                                24m      %    And modulo'd by 24
                                   c1[   %    Push the minutes
                                      {  %    Pair the two items
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 119 bytes

Input: `hh:mm`
Output: `h:mm`

```cs
t=>String.Concat("Accra,Lagos,Rome,Kyiv,Dubai".Split(',').Select((c,i)=>c+$":{(int.Parse(t[0..2])+i)%24}:{t[3..5]}\n"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BSsNAFEXXzlc8B6Xv0XEYEguamIAobuxCmoWL2sU4TuuDOJHMVJGQb0@x3dzDOavr4pWLPD3tg7uLqeewU3BiDVuoplTVzVH1QxecTSjvneutWtpdF9Wq@/Lq@Y9/1OP@3bLUzXfLCWdqRrrxrXcJ0SmmqnbzC1kMyCHpF9tHj2lttM42NGe6zK7HYkjrXOvFZnwLkmgqhTjdgFiK309uPSBGqGDl7ceSg0ciOK9ASoJBnL32nPwxbzESlWKcjClyI8zN/2Z5sbgVBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 548 bytes

Golfed vesrion, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBRS8MwGPwrn6VbUoxs7SZoQ4X6bEXwSRiO0qU22qa1SRlj1r9ek2zaDXxJvgt3912uYW15PQydZCBVyzNFzbhNW8HFm6TVDiaKV2xd57lkSkIEGMWqYEIiiO5gQdA94@@aa@ENQQ@12NTCIp@gR7aFl7r9sPhqSdAzq7vSolvPuLtcNJ3StsgPwsUc4gSZZ@wWddcScCsuOsX0kFZN5Wner@AbZq94tdn7JOi90Ez6BhwnX0@J584oz7WJEQH7BPSUIJhOwbrCRQR@4MH@gC4Noj2wUp5r4lNNdKaJYE57003G1W5tCpJ0W/CSAbbhzbPOfCjNpGZpVpw3qb3M98s6S8v10RQfE43KCQRL6o5b9nbuNVc2LRcqx85kHmxCczjk1O6vO4/2/0QzbmOwcYGOZY3BsczwwFwJh/bD8AM)

```perl
use strict;use warnings;my %time_offsets = ('Athens' => 3,'Beijing' => 8,'London' => 1,'New York' => -4,'Seoul' => 9);my $input = '12:30 AM';my ($hour, $minute, $ampm) = $input =~ /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM)$/;if ($ampm eq 'PM' && $hour != 12) {$hour += 12;} elsif ($ampm eq 'AM' && $hour == 12) {$hour = 0;}my %city_times;while (my ($city, $offset) = each %time_offsets) {my $local_hour = ($hour + $offset) % 24;$city_times{$city} = sprintf("%02d:%02d", $local_hour, $minute);}while (my ($city, $time) = each %city_times) {print "$city: $time\n";}
```

Ungolfed vesrion

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %time_offsets = (
    'Athens' => 3,
    'Beijing' => 8,
    'London' => 1,
    'New York' => -4,
    'Seoul' => 9,
);

my $input = '12:30 AM';  # Replace with input from user

# Extract hour, minute, and AM/PM from input
my ($hour, $minute, $ampm) = $input =~ /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM)$/;

# Convert 12-hour time to 24-hour time
if ($ampm eq 'PM' && $hour != 12) {
    $hour += 12;
} elsif ($ampm eq 'AM' && $hour == 12) {
    $hour = 0;
}

# Calculate time in each city
my %city_times;
while (my ($city, $offset) = each %time_offsets) {
    my $local_hour = ($hour + $offset) % 24;
    $city_times{$city} = sprintf("%02d:%02d", $local_hour, $minute);
}

# Output city times
while (my ($city, $time) = each %city_times) {
    print "$city: $time\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 123 bytes

Input can be in 12 or 24 hour format `i.e. hh:mm OR hh:mm AM/PM`

```powershell
param($i)0..4|%{"{0}: {1}"-f("Accra","Lagos","Cairo","Amman","Dubai")[$_],([datetime]$i).AddHours($_).ToString("hh:mm tt")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczBCsIgGADgVxk/CxSWuOi0m9ShQ53qNsb422wKcw7n6GA@u3n6bt9qv9JtSs5zSis6NKTUlDN2/h0CBB6bItQRjh8CYhgcQgV3nOyWvaB2NiuMwSV73d@ogbZl31WkHdFLr43scsfEON7s7jZS9pS97NM7vUwElGqMKbwHGlNKNW9OvBCPPw)